# New way to disable Skype phone number links on web site without breaking the number?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, skype, phone-number

The old way I was disabling Skype icons / links on webpages (which I found on this site) no longer seems to work.

I've tried:
1.
Adding this to the head:

```
<meta name="SKYPE_TOOLBAR" content="SKYPE_TOOLBAR_PARSER_COMPATIBLE" />
```

2.

```
span.skype_pnh_container {display:none !important;}
span.skype_pnh_print_container {display:inline !important;}
```

3.
Adding these CSS rules:

```
span[class^='skype_pnh_container'] {display:none !important;}
span[class^='skype_pnh_print_container'] {display:inline !important;}
```

None seem to work for me anymore.

I don't want to resort to breaking the phone number with span tags as it won't be clickable on devices.

If anyone knows of a new way to disable the styles as of October 2013 I'd be very appreciative. Thanks,

Comment: try to play a little bit with `<meta name="SKYPE_TOOLBAR" content="SKYPE_TOOLBAR_PARSER_COMPATIBLE"/>` or `<meta name="SKYPE_TOOLBAR" content="SKYPE_TOOLBAR_PARSER_COMPATIBLE" >` or `<meta name="SKYPE_TOOLBAR" content="SKYPE_TOOLBAR_PARSER_COMPATIBLE">`

Comment: and `<meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection">`

Comment: What if you go ahead and break it up in some way, but surround it with a link like `<a href="tel:+1800229933">[broken up number here]</a>` ?

Answer (score 3):

Change all the numbers to anchor tags () and add the link for example:

```
<a href="tel:123456789">123456789</a>
```

`href="tel:"` works like the `href="mailto:"` so it works on mobile device and with Skype if it is installed on the clients computer.

Hope this helps

Comment: The best solution, IMO.  Take control of the telephone number with my own anchor tag so Skype will not need "discover" it and mutilate the page. Brilliant!

Answer (score 2):

Try adding also style:

```
img.skype_pnh_logo_img {display: none !important }
```

to remove the click-to-call icon.

You could also use some JQuery like

```
$(".skype_pnh_container").attr("onmouseover", "").attr("onclick", "")
```

to remove the onmouseover and onclick handlers added by Skype. In order to properly time it I would suggest a combination between `$( document ).ready()` and `setTimeout`.

You could also exploit the limitations of the click-to-call plugin documented here
https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12006/how-do-i-script-webpages-to-find-phone-numbers-using-click-to-call

> Important:
>
> Do not use two identical delimiters together (for example,
> two space symbols or two hyphens). Such numbers will not be
> recognized.
>
> Do not use two non-space delimiters together (for example,
> hyphen and round bracket): +1-(862)-3135071.  If you wish to use
> several delimiters (two or more) at once, put a space symbol between
> the two non-space delimiters:
>
> +1 - (862) - 3135071
>
> +1 - 862 - 3135071.
>
> Do not use unsupported delimiters (such as []).

So if you use two non-space delimiters right after the other (dash and bracket) or some unsupported delimiter, this would ensure that Skype click-to-call plugin would not be able to detect the phone number.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](http://demosthenes.info/blog/536/Adding-Phone-Numbers-To-Web-Pages-With-HTML5-&-Microdata) on the Demosthenes blog, all you need to do to thwart Skype's interaction with IE is to use at least 1 **soft hyphen** in the number.  The HTML entity for a soft hyphen is `&shy;` or `&#173;`.

Comment: The link broken